# How can I make such a modification on the element of string array in a for loop which do not valid for the whole loop?

Tags: ibm-doors

My problem is related to formatting the elements of string array. I would like to apply lower case letter for all lines in the string array in a foor loop.

However, in the same for loop but later I need to use again these strings in their original forms. Unfortunaltely, I cannot find any solution to reorder the letters to original variant. I have to use strictly an earlier part of DOORS formal module the variant of lower case letters.

How I can achive this result in DXL?

Example:

I have a string array which contains the following terms:

AbCDefg

aBcdEFG

etc.

And finally I would like to see the result in the first usage in the for loop:

abcdefg

abcdefg

etc

And the second usage I would like to see the original element of string array:

AbCDefg

aBcdEFG

etc.

Comment: Where is the problem? You can write a function that takes as input your old array and the output is a new array with lowercase letters, this function should not change the input array. Then you create a second function that again takes your input array and does something different with it..

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by creating a function that will return a new array containing the lowercase values of the input. This means the original values will not be altered, and you can use them again.

```
string originalArray[] = {"This ", "is ", "A ", "TeSt ", "STRING"}

string lowercaseArray[] = null

string arrayToLower(string input[])[] {
    int inputSize = sizeof(input)
    string result[inputSize]
    int i

    for (i = 0; i < inputSize; i++) {
        result[i] = lower(input[i])
    }

    return result
}

lowercaseArray= arrayToLower(originalArray)

int count = sizeof(lowercaseArray)
int j
for(j=0;j<count;j++) {
    print(lowercaseArray[j] "\n")
}
```

This code example provides a function `arrayToLower()`, if you pass in a string array, it will return a new array with the lowercase values of the original. The full example above will show it working with some test data, the only bit you will want is:

```
string arrayToLower(string input[])[] {
    int inputSize = sizeof(input)
    string result[inputSize]
    int i

    for (i = 0; i < inputSize; i++) {
        result[i] = lower(input[i])
    }

    return result
}
```